# Crashlytics: Using build server to make a release and upload the distribution of an Android App

Tags: android, ant, jenkins, proguard, crashlytics

I'm using **Crashlytics** to distribute the Android app when making a build with the Build Server (Jenkins).

I've followed the instructions here: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/388924-beta-distributions-with-ant

Whenever I make a build through Jenkins has the ant commands described:

```
clean
release
crashlytics-upload-distribution -DbetaDistributionGroupAliases="team-android"
```

But I always get the error:

```
BUILD FAILED
Target "crashlytics-upload-distribution" does not exist in the project "release".
```

For additional information, my file `custom_rules.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="crashlytics_custom_rules" default="help">
    <!-- See the instructions at the top of crashlytics_build.xml
         for information about nonstandard builds. -->

    <import file="crashlytics/crashlytics_build.xml"/>

</project>
```

The files: `crashlytics_build_base.xml` &   `crashlytics_build.xml` were not changed.

Also I'm using proguard on the builds, on the proguard-project.txt I've added:

```
# Crashlytics - To show correctly the stacktraces
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

Can someone point me to what might be the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I had several `build.xml`.

The one on the root folder was not the `build.xml` that imports Android default nor `custom_rules.xml`

I needed to invoke the

> ant release crashlytics-upload-distribution
>   -DbetaDistributionGroupAliases="team-android"

from the custom `build.xml`